# Optimize query SQL (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I need to get all records from table1 minus all (matching) records in table2. Green zone in the image.

[image: The greenzone]

The matching has to be done by pairs (values from 2 columns)
Here is the query that I'm doing:

`SELECT col1, col2
FROM table1
WHERE (col1, col2) NOT IN
    (SELECT col1, col2 
     FROM table2)`

tabel1 has 317789 records and table2 has 289639 records.
I got index(col1), index(col2) and index(col1, col2) on both tables.

Query is runnig for over than 30min now... Help!! :)

Comment: `IN`/`NOT IN` with multiple values can't use indexes in MySQL. You should avoid it.

Comment: See case four of [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) = second Left outer join, and adjust for using pairs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd go with a null left join:

```
select col1, col2 from table1
left join table2 on table1.col1=table2.col1 and table1.col2 = table2.col2
where table2.<pk field> is null;
```

This will then show you the records from table1 that have no match in table2.

Note that pk field means whatever the primary key field in table2 is.

Comment: Thanks, running it now.

Comment: Query still taking more than 35min... Is this normal for the volume of records that i have?? A simple Left/Right/Inner JOIN takes less than a minute over the same tables...

Comment: It varies is all I can say.

You could try something like:  

    select * from table1
    left join table2 on table2.key = (select key from table2 where 
    table2.col1 = table1.col1 and table2.col2 = table1.col2)
    where table2.key is null;

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT table1.col1, table1.col2 
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 
ON table2.col1 = table1.col1 AND table2.col2 = table1.col2
```

look at this "cheatsheet" of joins

[image]

Comment: This is good but not solve Drews problem. Should be 'where table2.pk is null'

Comment: You forgot the "is null" clause. But thanks for the cheat sheet ;)

Comment: The second one down on the left is the example you want. Also, iirc mysql does not support full outer joins, but there are ways to kludge one.

Comment: you are right. I would not edit my answer and agree with first answer :)))